# How to synchronously query data from room database?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room

This is my first time doing android dev. Sorry for my lack of knowledge in..well everything.

I am trying to query some data on the main thread of an activity using asynctask. The problem is, the data that I queried is needed immediately in some other query of data, so the asynchronous nature of the query means that every time I need to use the data, the thread has not queried it yet and gives a nullpointer exception. 
Is there a way to synchronously query data from room database?

I tried the getValue() function from a LiveData object, but it always returns null as well. I am sure that the data is inserted properly within the database, I have checked multiple times looking into the database while debugging.

This is the code I used to query an entity of Day class:

```
 //load current day
        findSpecificDayAsyncTask asyncTask = (findSpecificDayAsyncTask) new findSpecificDayAsyncTask(mDayDao, new findSpecificDayAsyncTask.AsyncResponse() {

            @Override
            public void processFinish(Day output) {
                day1 = output;
            }
}).execute(date);
```

It works in due time, but I need the data immediately so that I can query
some other data:

```
mBPViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BulletPointViewModel.class);

                         //the day1 class is used here as a parameter
        mBPViewModel.getSpecificDayBulletPoints(day1.day).observe(this, new Observer<List<BulletPoint>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<BulletPoint> bulletPoints) {
                // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                mAdapter.setBulletPoints(bulletPoints);
            }
        });
```

So is there a way for me to synchronously query data so I don't get
a nullpointer exception?

Comment: Did you consider using an Executor (Thread Pools) rather than AsyncTask?

Comment: @MohammadL No I haven't, and to be honest, I didn't know about it until you mentioned it. Do you know any good tutorials on how to use it? And also, if you execute multiple tasks at once, is it guaranteed that they were executed, or is it the fastest task is finished first?

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing like this

```
    //load current day
    findSpecificDayAsyncTask asyncTask = (findSpecificDayAsyncTask) new 
    findSpecificDayAsyncTask(mDayDao, new findSpecificDayAsyncTask.AsyncResponse() {

        @Override
        public void processFinish(Day output) {
            day1 = output;
            mBPViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BulletPointViewModel.class);
             //the day1 class is used here as a parameter
            mBPViewModel.getSpecificDayBulletPoints(day1.day).observe(this, new Observer<List<BulletPoint>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<BulletPoint> bulletPoints) {
                    // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
                    mAdapter.setBulletPoints(bulletPoints);
                }
            });
        }

    }).execute(date);
```